# Can I make class method in Python to take argument in type of this class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I want to specify, that some method takes argument in same type, like this function.

I try to explain by example of animals

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name : str):
        self.name = name

    def say_hello(self, animal: Animal):
        print(f"Hi {animal.name}")
```

name with type str doesn't make any problems, but Animal is not recognized:

```
NameError: name 'Animal' is not defined
```

I use PyCharm and Python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

The class name is not available because it is not yet defined at this point. Since Python 3.7, you can enable postponed evaluation of annotations ([PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)) by adding this line before any imports or code:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Alternatively, you can use string annotations, which should be recognised by most type checkers, including the one built into PyCharm:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name: str):  # this annotation can be left as a class
        self.name = name

    def say_hello(self, animal: 'Animal'):  # this one is itself a string
        print(f"Hi {animal.name}")
```

Comment: yep, this is the intended way of doing it. And static type-checkers / run-time inspectors will understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a type with `typing.NewType` and inherit from it:

```
from typing import NewType

AnimalType = NewType('AnimalType', object)

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def say_hello(self, animal: AnimalType):
        print(f"Hi {animal.name}")
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy @AZW's needs, because `Animal('Tom').say_hello(Animal('Jerry'))` doesn't pass static type-checkers.